# Setting the Python path for local project in VS Code without using the settings.json file

Tags: python, git, conda, visual-studio-code

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32979933/2251982) from a Visual Studio Code developer says that it is reasonable to keep a Visual Studio Code project's `settings.json` file in a project's git repository to enforce code standards across different development environments. One down-side though is that when I select the Python interpreter path at the bottom of the screen (so the linter can find the installed packages), the following entry gets added to the `settings.json` file:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/path/to/conda/envs/my-env-name/bin/python",
```

This path is local to the machine and assumes that conda is being used. I have to avoid adding this setting to the `settings.json` that I commit to the git repository, which is annoying.

Is there a way to set the Python path locally for a project without writing a setting into the `settings.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

It currently isn't directly supported, but we have a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2125) that you can upvote if you would like to see it prioritized.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to:

- remove that line from the local workspace `settings.json`
- copy-paste it to your User `settings.json`

See "[VSCode User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)".

That way, your Git codebase can keep a generic `settings.json` without local path.

Since this would work for only *one* project, you can instead reference all your projects in several [Multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).

Then, regarding settings in that environment, you have three files:

- Preferences: Open User Settings - Open your global User settings
- references: Open Workspace Settings - Open the settings section of your Workspace file.
- Preferences: Open Folder Settings - Open the settings for the active folder.

That means you could switch workspaces, and in each multi-root workspace (each one composed of only *one* root), you would keep:

- the global `pythonPath` path in user settings (applies to everything, everywhere)
- the specific `pythonPath` for a given multi-root workspace in the Workspace setting (outside of the project folder which is the only root for that "multi-root" workspace)
- the public versioned `settings.json` project-specific settings in the project folder (which is the only root of the workspace)

Again, by switching workspace, you can differentiate between:

- workspace-specific private settings, local to your computer, like a `pythonPath`
- project specific settings, in the project folder, that you can version and publish.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. I assume though that it's not possible to set this on a per-project basis, since it's in the shared user settings file? I have other conda environments for other projects.

Comment: @Sean Right! I didn't think of that. I propose a workaround, using multi-root workspaces. See my edited answer.